# Visitor Pattern and Encapsulation

Tags: c#, design-patterns

The visitor design pattern is a way of separating an algorithm from an object structure it operates on. That is official definition of it. I am trying to figure out how this doesn't break encapsulation. If say for example I have different types of classes for different types of bank accounts [Saving/Fixed/Current] implementing abstract class Account, should I put the calculate interest method as an abstract method in the abstract Account class or do I send the account type to the Visitor implementation and calculate it there?

**Method 1:** Should the Visitor implementation be responsible for calculating interest for the different account types?

```
public interface IInterestVisitor
{
    void GetInterest(Savings AccountType);
    void GetInterest(Fixed AccountType);
    void GetInterest(Current AccountType);
}
```

**Method 2:** Or should the Account class's implementers do it?

```
public abstract class Account
{
    public abstract void AcceptCalculateInterestVisitor(IInterestVisitor iv);
    public abstract int CalculateInterestAmount();
}
```

If I use method 1, which is the visitor implementation that implements IInterestVisitor as above, then the job of calculating interest will be delegated to the visitor class. Using this approach, if I add another account type, then I will need to modify the visitor implementation everytime a new account comes along.

However, if I leave the interest calculation bit to the abstract Account classes implementations as above in method 2, then in my opinion [*correct me if I am wrong here*] I am not breaking encapsulation. In addition there is less code to modify as all I do is add a new class and have the visitor implement an interface like the one below

```
public interface IInterestVisitor
{
    void GetInterest(Account AccountType);
}


public class InterestVisitor : IInterestVisitor
{
    public void GetInterest(Account AccountType)
    {
        int i = AccountType.CalculateInterestAmount();
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is no modification needed for the interest visitor class using method 2. Does method 1 break encapsulation? Can method 2 still be called a visitor pattern?

Thanks for reading...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Visitor lets you define a new operation without changing the classes
>   of the elements on which it operates.

In code provided I don't see that you need to change an  object in order to fit your needs, what `Visitor` basically does, is change object state by using provided `Properties`/`Methods`/`Fields` of object itself.

So, by me your code can fit Visitor pattern, if that was actually question, also cause patterns are *guidelines* and *not* rigid rules.

I personally would chose second way, as it much more clear and OOP oriented.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks. I did understand from the visitors definition that the visitor  pattern is used to change the object state by using provided Properties/Methods/Fields of object itself. I'm having a hard time figuring out why wont any such changes to be made, be provided for by the original class itself; without having to add a visitor to do it. Seems to me that a visitor was added as an after thought to do more on that class in a manner that doesn't break existing code that is already working on that class. What do you think? :)

Comment: Visitor basically works on object by using object's provided artifacts or their agregation. If you need to 0 balance and Disable credit card, you can define on object to functions BalanceToZero() and DisableCreditCard() and in visitor call them in sequence. NON Visitor approach BASICALLY, would be declare a third function on object ZeroBalanceAndDisableCard() function where you call both functions. By the way the concept of design patterns often is "foggy" so usually I need to "refactor" them based on my needs.

Comment: Though Visitor is allowed to change the object state, since it has got the object, a general recommendation is to not to change the object state. The functionality like display report on screen, print the receipt, read out the report by voice is an good example.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see the need for a visitor here at all - your approach perfectly illustrates that you can solve this problem just with polymorphism using a `CalculateInterestAmount` method the subclasses can implement.

In my opinion you really need a very compelling case to consider using the Visitor pattern - most of the time other solutions are more straightforward and fit more naturally.

Having said that, your version 2 is really just using polymorphism - there's no benefit of using a Visitor this way. Version 1 illustrates the "double dispatch" approach of a visitor better, this is how a visitor generally works.

Comment: Thanks. I was just trying to go with a simple example for illustration  purposes :) I'd assume that if this were a real world scenario then it would be method 2 followed by a universal action on all account types in the GetInterest method of the InterestVisitor implementation. Correct?

Comment: @user20358: Method 2 doesn't really take advantage of the Visitor being able to execute *different* code depending on the actual type of the class being visited - it just uses polymorphism, hence there is no advantage in using a Visitor in the first place. Method 1 is more appropriate in general for a Visitor - although it does not make sense in your simple example.

Answer (score 1):

Visitor helps in situations where the logic may depend upon both type of the type of the Visted as well as the type of Visitor - it's a way of structuring double dispatch.

In your scenario you have a requirement to calculate interest and this is a reasonable operation of an account and depends very clearly on the nature of the account. Hence as you point out Visitor adds no value, and seems inappropriate.

Now lets take a slightly more complex set of calculations. Imagine that you have a variety of savings accounts some are regular savings accounts, some are conditional on stock market behaviours, some have elements of life-insurance. For such accounts we have methods to obtains data such interest rates, bonus rates, regular payment schedules, maturity dates and so on, each different for different types of accounts.

We also need to perform certain calculations: what's predicted value of the account on a certain date? What's the account's value as loan collatoral now? What's the value of the account if closed today. Such calculations will need to be done differently (perhaps using the raw data getters) for each account type.

Now we see some value in a Visitor pattern. As we devise a new interesting calculation we write a new Visitor, we don't need to release new versions of the account classes.

Comment: Thanks :) ..Any pointers on how to figure out in what kinda situations a visitor could be a good fit?

Comment: The key is "double dispatch". In my example the algorithm depends on the type of account and the type of calculation. Further, it's clear that both types of calculation and types of account can increase independently.

Answer (score 1):

@Tigran pointed out that Visitor is useful when you can't change the classes being visited.

Since you are using C#, it is probably more modular and effective to use [Extension Methods](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/csharp-3.0/extension-methods/).  They do the same thing, adding functionality to a type after the fact, but you no longer need to carry around all of the possible implementations in one place.

Comment: Yep but they are still static methods and you do not have any kind of polymorphism so it makes solution less flexible. I would say Extension Methods are good for some kind of util operations

Comment: @silev Neither breaks encapsulation, and a person who strives for a visitor pattern almost always uses it incorrectly.  Case in point, to be a conventional visitor, `GetInterest` should be replaced with a method called `Visit` and a class derived from the visitor might be a `GetInterestVisitor`, and another with `ClearDailyLogVisitor`.  The visitor is preferable in cases where I would like to attach work items to a queue, yet I'm unsure of what that work might actually be, or I would like the flexibility to change what sort of work I am doing in the future.

Comment: absolutely, I can not suggest anything regarding Visitor in scope of this particular question. I just said that from my point of view Extension Methods will introduce more coupled code and gives you less flexibility maintaining and extending it because of statc EM

Comment: @silev Thank you.  I did misspeak that they "do the same thing," when there is obviously a time and place for each.

Answer (score 1):

Here is example of visitor which report the status in many ways without impacting the original Account classes/objects. It is not good to replace capabilities of Visitors in virtual functions like PrintReport(), SmsReport() etc where you will have too many methods to implement. Using Visitor, you could extend the capabilities in other way without affecting the object. **I gave this example, since you have asked/mentioned where a visitor would fits**.. In my opinion, visitor would not fit both the methods you have mentioned.

```
public interface IAccount
{
    //Below are properties and methods which you expose outside
    // accoring to your class/domain
    double Interest { get;}
    //double Balance { get;}
    //ContactInfo Contact{ get;}
    void Visit(IAccountVisitor visitor);
}

public class AccountBase
{
}

public class FixedDeposit: AccountBase, IAccount
{
    double Interest { 
            get{
                return  CalculateInterest(); //don't change object state                    
            }
                    ;}

    protected double CalculateInterest()
    {
        return <<your expression to calculate>>;
    }

    public void Visit(IAccountVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}

public class XYZBlashBlahDeposit: AccountBase, IAccount
{
    public void Visit(IAccountVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}

...
...

public interface IAccountVisitor
{
    //void Report(IAccount account); //This is prefered and safe and 
    void Visit(Account account);
}

public class PrintReportVisitor: IAccountVisitor
{
    public void Visit(Account account)
    {
        //Get object information
        //Print to printer
    }
}

public class DisplayReportVisitor: IAccountVisitor
{
    public void Visit(Account account)
    {
        //Get object information
        //Display on monitor
    }
}

public class ReportAudioVisitor: IAccountVisitor
{
    public void Visit(Account account)
    {
        //Get object information
        //Read out the information
    }
}

public class SmsReportVisitor: IAccountVisitor
{
    public void Visit(Account account)
    {
        //Get object information
        //Send SMS to my mobile registered with account
    }
}

public class EmailReportVisitor: IAccountVisitor
{
    public void Visit(Account account)
    {
        //Get object information
        //Send Email to my email registered with account
    }
}
```

See if you have application, how to use Visitor.

```
public class ReportViewer: UserControl
{
    IAccount _Account;
    public ReportViewer(IAccount account)
    {  
         this._Account = account;
         InitializeComponent();
    }
    void btnClick_Print()
    {
        _Account.Visit(new PrintReportVisitor());
    }

    void btnClick_ViewReport()
    {
        _Account.Visit(new DisplayReportVisitor(this));
    }

    void btnClick_SendSMS()
    {
        _Account.Visit(new SMSReportVisitor(this));
    }

    void btnClick_SendEmail()
    {
        _Account.Visit(new EmailReportVisitor(this));
    }
}
```